# Vault transit engine key lease duration

Tags: encryption, hashicorp-vault, vault, hashicorp

I see the following output after creating a key with [HashiCorp vault’s transit engine](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/api-docs/secret/transit#create-key) using `vault write -f transit/keys/transit_key exportable=true` command-

```
...
“lease duration”: 0,
“lease_id”: “”,
“renewable”: false
...
```

Does this mean that the key is valid for infinity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right. A `lease duration` of 0 would mean the key wouldn't expire and valid for infinity.

Though it is generally not a good security practice to set a `lease duration` of 0.